# Odds of related events

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I am working on casino kind of game for which I need to find probabilities, I will try to simplify by using small part of larger set of problem where I am stuck.

I have bingo like game of 20 balls having numbers only 
1 to 5 in equal count of 4 each.

Balls I have as follows,
1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5

Game is to pick randomly a single ball Everytime. If all of balls with same numbers are drawn first, that number wins and game ends.

If say 2 cards are drawn both "1" each, odds will be in favor of 1.
How do I calculate odds for 1 at this case.
I am not looking for answer but a way to formulate easy way of calculation for non stat guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to know the probability of the number $1$ winning conditional on the first two balls drawn being $1$s. This is $\frac2{18}\cdot\frac1{17}=\frac1{153}$, since the third ball needs to be one of two $1$s out of $18$ remaining balls and the fourth ball needs to be the single remaining $1$ out of $17$ remaining balls.

Hmm – now I’m thinking that perhaps you don’t mean that all $1$s have to be drawn first, but rather that whatever number has all its balls drawn first wins. In that case, you can calculate the winning probability for $1$ after two $1$s have been drawn by [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The $1$s lose against the $2$s exactly if a $1$ is the last number among the six balls $2,2,2,2,1,1$, and the probability for this is $\frac26=\frac13$. Likewise, the $1$s lose against two other numbers with probability $\frac2{10}=\frac15$, against three other numbers with probability $\frac2{14}=\frac17$ and against all four other numbers with probability $\frac2{18}=\frac19$, so by inclusion–exclusion the winning probability for $1$ is

$$
1-\binom41\cdot\frac13+\binom42\cdot\frac15-\binom43\cdot\frac17+\binom44\cdot\frac19=\frac{128}{315}\;.
$$

I’m not sure whether this counts as the “easy way of calculation” you were looking for; if I can think of an easier way, I’ll update the answer.

---

In response to the comment:

The same basic principles apply, but since there’s no longer symmetry among the four other numbers, we get a few more different terms. If $11122345$ have been drawn, the $1$s lose against the $2$s if the remaining $1$ is the last number among the three balls $1$, $2$, $2$, with probability $\frac13$, whereas against the $3$s the $1$ has to be the last among $1$, $3$, $3$, $3$, with probability $\frac14$, and likewise against the $4$s and the $5$s. Similarly for the pairs, triples and quadruples, e.g. the $1$s lose against the $2$s and $3$s with probability $\frac16$, against the $2$, $3$ and $4$s with probability $\frac19$, etc. Altogether, the inclusion–exclusion sum in this case is

$$
1-\frac13-3\cdot\frac14+3\cdot\frac16+3\cdot\frac17-3\cdot\frac19-\frac1{10}+\frac1{12}=\frac{52}{105}\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks that was great,. And quick, one question, how would we choose combinations when uneven numbers of all balls have been drawn, say 3 balls of 1'ss and 2 balls of 2's, 1 ball of 3's and 1 balls of 4's and 5's each

Comment: @GaurangSheth: I've added that calculation to the answer.